# Algorithm for column, row from index?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

Say I have an index 12 (12th element) going from left to right, top to bottom.

I have an array[4][4].

What would be the fastest way to compute the index [3][2] given the 1D index 12? (1D index starts at 1).

Thanks

Comment: `index[3][2]` is not equivalent to `index[12]`. `[3][2]` covers 15 cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is fastest, but it's definitely simple:

Assuming array[x][y]

```
ix = floor(index / y)
iy = index % y
```

Example:

```
01
23
45

x = 3
y = 2

index = 3
ix = floor(3 / 2) = 1
iy = 3 % 2 = 1    

index = 5
ix = floor(5 / 2) = 2
iy = 5 % 2 = 1
```

Comment: I think you have done it reverse. Remainder should go in `iy`.

Comment: yeah, while the general idea was there I had a couple things off, fixed it up, thanks

Comment: I need  to wait 5 mins, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

given a[x][y] is the array

use this formula

```
[index of 1d array]= (rnum * colsize) + (colnum + 1)
```

so for a[3][2] with `colsize=4`

```
= (3 * 4) + (2 + 1)
= 15
```